# Calling and Passing a DLL variables C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll

I have a source file file.cpp and within it I need to access a DLL `file.dll`. Also I need access to the function `DoFunction` within `file.dll` and I need to pass it some variables from the `file.cpp`.

I have:

```
m_hinstPtiDLL = LoadLibrary("file.dll");
pGNSI = (PGNSI) GetProcAddress(m_hinstPtiDLL, "DoFunction");
```

I want to be able to pass `DoFunction` 7 variables and have it return the necessary value.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This will return a pointer to the function.

```
pGNSI = (PGNSI)GetProcAddress(m_hinstPtiDLL, "DoFunction");
```

If it is not `NULL` then simply call it. For example, if the signature of the function expects 7 parameters:

```
if (pGNSI)
{
    pGNSI(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7);
}
```

Comment: This is the function from the DLL when I try and do as you said I get error C2197: 'PGNSI' : too many arguments for call

(It takes 10 not 7 sorry)

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) Error_t DoFunction(
 ui8 *cdb,
 ui8 cdblen,
 ui8 *buffer,
 ui8 nHa,
 ui8 tid,
 ui16 timeout,
 ui32 buffer_length,
 ui32 transfer_direction,
 ui8 *senseBuffer,
 ui32 *cmdId)

Comment: @Kyle Why did you say in the question that it takes 7 parameters, but now you want to pass it 10? You have to pass the same number of arguments as are listed in the function prototype.

Comment: See in parentheses where it says it takes 10 not 7. It doesn't matter either way it takes 10 I gave it 10 I'm still getting that error.

Comment: PGNSI - is it something you defined ?
I mean, it is possible that DoSomething and PGNSI have different signatures.

Comment: @artapet typedef void (WINAPI *PGNSI)(LPSYSTEM_INFO); I am wrapping up someone else's code so I'm not completely familiar with it.

Comment: @Kyle That's the signature for the [`GetNativeSystemInfo` Win32 function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340.aspx). It needs to be called dynamically (i.e., using implicit linking) because it's not available on all versions of Windows. That function does not take 7 parameters, or 10. It just takes one, a pointer to a `SYSTEM_INFO` struct. So something's getting confused here.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have taken the example from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

pGNSI should be a pointer to function of the exact prototype of your function defined in DLL. If you have this function in the DLL:

```
void myFunc(int arg1, int arg2);
```

Then pGNSI should be:

```
typedef void (*pGNSI)(int arg1, int arg2);
```

Then you shouldn't get an error.

A good approach to do this is to provide an exported header file from your DLL which declares the function pointer and include this header in the application. This makes the definition consistent and error free.